Why does TanStack Router redirect me even if Zustand has updated its store before? Login Problem
I've a problem with my login conception, with Zustand and TanStack Router.
I click on my login button the function fires and gives me the feedback, but
the store isn't updated in my RouterWithContext. This is why i get redirected on my AppRoute back to my login form. The Problem is that my call in the AuthPage did't update my store correctly so that my context is correct. If i click my login button for a second time, i can "login", because the store is now updated.
I think my Problem is in my App.tsx with the context.
const App = () => {
    const auth = useGlobalStore((state) => state);
    return (
        <MantineProvider theme={workshopWizardTheme} cssVariablesResolver={wwVariablesResolver}>
            <RouterProvider router={router} context={{ auth }} />
        </MantineProvider>
    );
};

export default App;

Here are the other files of my project:
auth-slice.ts store.ts App Route Auth Page Root Route
What i did so far to resolve my problem:
Implemented logs to see where my point of failure is.
Tried to read the docs of Zustand to see if the problem is related to Zustand.
Rearranged my code some times. And i read some StackOverflow Topics with this setup,
but nobody used the store as context in a contextRoute.

Maybe you should try wrapping navigate in a setTimeout
